Waybar Not Restarting – Script for Generating Waybar Colors with Pywal
I wrote a script to change Waybar's colors using the colors automatically generated by pywal. This script successfully changes Waybar's colors automatically. However, there is an issue with restarting Waybar, when using the 'pkill waybar' command, I get a 'Terminated' output in the terminal, and the subsequent operations do not occur.
# This script will change your waybar colors using pywal colors
# Usage ./update_waybar.sh (don't forget to `sudo chmod +x ./update_waybar.sh`)

# Path to the Pywal colors
PYWAL_COLORS="$HOME/.cache/wal/colors.json"

# Path to the Waybar style file
WAYBAR="$HOME/.config/waybar/style.css"

# Default colors (will be used if Pywal colors are not generated/available)
DEFAULT_WAYBAR_BACKGROUND="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)"

# Function to extract value from JSON
get_json_value() {
    echo "$1" | grep -oP '"'"$2"'": *"\K[^"]*'
}

# Function to convert hex color to rgba with transparency
hex_to_rgba() {
    hex=$1
    r=$(echo $hex | cut -c2-3)
    g=$(echo $hex | cut -c4-5)
    b=$(echo $hex | cut -c6-7)

    # Convert hex to decimal
    r=$((16#${r}))
    g=$((16#${g}))
    b=$((16#${b}))

    # Return rgba format with alpha set to 0.4 for transparency
    echo "rgba($r, $g, $b, 0.4)"
}

echo "Looking for pywal colors..."

if [ ! -f "$PYWAL_COLORS" ]; then
    echo "Pywal colors not found, using default colors."
    WAYBAR_BACKGROUND=$DEFAULT_WAYBAR_BACKGROUND
else
    echo "Pywal colors found, reading colors."
    WAYBAR_BACKGROUND=$(get_json_value "$(cat $PYWAL_COLORS)" "color8")
    echo "Using color8: $WAYBAR_BACKGROUND"

    # If the color is in hex format, convert it to rgba
    if [[ "$WAYBAR_BACKGROUND" =~ ^#[0-9a-fA-F]{6}$ ]]; then
        WAYBAR_BACKGROUND=$(hex_to_rgba $WAYBAR_BACKGROUND)
        echo "Converted hex to rgba: $WAYBAR_BACKGROUND"
    fi
fi

# Update Waybar's style.css with the new background color
echo "Updating Waybar colors..."

# Check if the style.css already contains a rgba or hex for the background-color
if grep -q "background-color" "$WAYBAR"; then
    # Replace the background-color line inside window#waybar
    sed -i "/window#waybar {/,/}/s|background-color: .*;|background-color: $WAYBAR_BACKGROUND;|" "$WAYBAR"
else
    # If there's no background-color, add the background-color property
    sed -i "/window#waybar {/a background-color: $WAYBAR_BACKGROUND;" "$WAYBAR"
fi

# Restart Waybar to apply changes
echo "Restarting Waybar..."
pkill waybar
nohup waybar &>/dev/null &

echo "Waybar colors updated!"

After thinking about this for a while, I found a solution. When I close Waybar this way:
WAYBAR_PID=$(pgrep -x "waybar")
kill "$WAYBAR_PID"

it doesn't cause any issues, and the script successfully changes the colors and then restarts Waybar. However, I didn't like closing it this way for several reasons. What is the reason I can't do this with 'pkill' ? Or is there another way to solve this problem? I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

I think I found the cause of the problem. Since the name of my file is "update_waybar.sh", the "pkill waybar" command also terminates this script. I can solve the issue by renaming the file, but is there any way to fix this without changing the file name?

pkill uses signal 15. Your script can ignore this signal when you add
# ignore signal 15
trap '' 15
# Or decide to sleep 1 second when pkill is busy killing stuff
trap 'sleep 1' 15

